# Spoiler works only with odd numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i want to expand the spoiler it is only working if there are odd spoilers added on a page.

How can i fix that, i tried also find.

HTML

```
<div class="kspoiler">
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <div class="kspoiler-title" style="display:inline-block;">
            <?php echo $this->title; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-expand" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input class="btn-link" type="button" id="kspoiler-show" value="<?php echo Text::_('COM_KUNENA_LIB_BBCODE_SPOILER_EXPAND'); ?>"/>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="kspoiler-content">
                <?php echo $this->content; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.kspoiler').each(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.kspoiler-expand', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            var show = $(this.children[0]).val() === Joomla.getOptions('com_kunena.expand');
            $(this.children[0]).val(show ? Joomla.getOptions('com_kunena.hide') : Joomla.getOptions('com_kunena.expand'));
            $(this).parent().children('.kspoiler-wrapper').toggle()
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we don't have Joomla her on SO I simplified your code a little bit and changed `Joomla.getOption('com_kunena.expand')` to `Joomla.com_kunena.expand`. But in the following snippet you can see that your code basically works - no matter how many section you have.

However, I removed your outer `$('.kspoiler').each(function () {...}` as this is *completely superfluous* and would assign the click event listener *multiple times* canceling each other out. This is most likely the reason why it only worked with odd numbers of sections!

When you are dealing with multiple sections you must also be careful to keep your `id`s unique! I removed the button Ids in your example to avoid trouble.

```js
var Joomla={com_kunena:{expand:"c'm on, show it!",hide:"quick - hide it!"}};
$('.btn-link').val(Joomla.com_kunena.expand);

$(document).on('click', '.kspoiler-expand', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   var show = $(this.children[0]).val() === Joomla.com_kunena.expand;
   $(this.children[0]).val(show ? Joomla.com_kunena.hide : Joomla.com_kunena.expand);
   $(this).parent().children('.kspoiler-wrapper').toggle()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kspoiler">
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <div class="kspoiler-title" style="display:inline-block;">
            1. Title from PHP
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-expand" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input class="btn-link" type="button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="kspoiler-content">
                Content from PHP
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <div class="kspoiler-title" style="display:inline-block;">
            2. Title from PHP
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-expand" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input class="btn-link" type="button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="kspoiler-content">
                Content from PHP
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <div class="kspoiler-title" style="display:inline-block;">
            3. Title from PHP
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-expand" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input class="btn-link" type="button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="kspoiler-content">
                Content from PHP
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <div class="kspoiler-title" style="display:inline-block;">
            4. Title from PHP
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-expand" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input class="btn-link" type="button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="kspoiler-content">
                Content from PHP
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><hr>
<div class="kspoiler">SECOND kspoiler DIV<br>
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <div class="kspoiler-title" style="display:inline-block;">
            1. Title from PHP
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-expand" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input class="btn-link" type="button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="kspoiler-content">
                Content from PHP
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <div class="kspoiler-title" style="display:inline-block;">
            2. Title from PHP
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-expand" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input class="btn-link" type="button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="kspoiler-content">
                Content from PHP
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <div class="kspoiler-title" style="display:inline-block;">
            3. Title from PHP
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-expand" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input class="btn-link" type="button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="kspoiler-content">
                Content from PHP
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <div class="kspoiler-title" style="display:inline-block;">
            4. Title from PHP
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-expand" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input class="btn-link" type="button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="kspoiler-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="kspoiler-content">
                Content from PHP
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.
`$('.kspoiler').each(function () {...}` removing that did the trick.